# getting http_statust 408 from cordova file transfer upload

Tags: javascript, php, apache, cordova

i cant seem to upload image on from cordova using filetransfer to apache server running lamp stack
always keep getting http_status : 408 and error code 3 from file transfer
im running cordova 3.5 which has file plugin 1.2.0 and filetransfer plugin 0.4.4

here is the code

```
$scope.transferFile = function (imageURI) {
    console.log(imageURI);
    //imageURI = imageURI.substr(8, imageURI.length);
    //imageURI = 'file://' + imageURI;
    //console.log(imageURI);

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();

    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.headers = {
        Connection: "close"
    };

    // setup parameters
    var params = {};
    params.fullpath =imageURI;
    params.name = options.fileName;



    var ft = new FileTransfer();

    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI('http://www.exoplace.com/uploads/upload.php'), win, fail, options);

}
```

here is image taking code

```
        var type;
    if (t == "gallery") {
        type = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
    } else {
        type = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
    }
    navigator.camera.getPicture($scope.transferFile, $scope.uploadFailed, {
        quality: 90,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: type,
        allowEdit: true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 500,
        targetHeight: 500,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    });
```

on server i just keep empty php page called upload.php which returns some random string and does nothing.

the server code is

```
echo 'test'
```

any idea is it server or client problem?

Comment: What's about the allowed file upload size of the server?

Comment: 2mb but i am uploading pic with size of 33kb

Comment: Error 3 is a connection error. If possible I would update the project. Cordova and the plugins are old.

Comment: on cordova 3.7.0 file 1.3.1 file transfer 0.4.8 same thing

Comment: on cordova 3.8.0 file 1.3.1 file transfer 0.5.0 same thing and i really cant go on cordova 4.0

Comment: just went to check keep alive is turned on on server.
408 http code is :
The Web server (running the Web site) thinks that there has been too long an interval of time between 1) the establishment of an IP connection (socket) between the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) and the server and 2) the receipt of any data on that socket, so the server has dropped the connection. The socket connection has actually been lost - the Web server has 'timed out' on that particular socket connection. The request from the client must be repeated - in a timely manner.